# Swap section title and section number in KOMA Script scrartcl

Tags: koma-script, titlesec, scrartcl

Since it is not recommended to use `titlesec` in KOMA script, I'm looking for some alternative to swap section title and section number, having

```
Title 1
```

instead of

```
1 Title
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

All solutions I found use the `titlesec` package - which work with `scrartcl` indeed, but produces warnings:

```
Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \section
(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \subsection
(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \subsubsection
(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \paragraph
(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command \subparagraph
(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
)
Class scrartcl Info: Unknown `titesec' release.
(scrartcl) Cross your fingers, that is compatible on input line 9.
```

How can I swap number and title without warnings in `scrartcl`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to redefine `\sectionlinesformat` and `\sectionformat`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4#3}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% original definition for subsection, subsubsection
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\enskip\thesection\autodot}

\begin{document}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Regarding a comment below: If you want to use page style `headings` then you can add

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \if@twoside\expandafter\markboth\else\expandafter\markright\fi
  {\MakeMarkcase{#1\Ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}}{}}%
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\enskip\thesection\autodot}
```

to swap section number and section title in header.

If there would be a table of contents add

```latex
\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2\enskip#1}}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifnumbered{\ifnumbered}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\pagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\enskip\thesection\autodot}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{\enskip\thesection\autodot}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2}{#4#3}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}}% original definition for subsection, subsubsection
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \if@twoside\expandafter\markboth\else\expandafter\markright\fi
  {\MakeMarkcase{#1\Ifnumbered{section}{\sectionmarkformat}{}}}{}}%
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}
    {\addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2\enskip#1}}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But that doesn't change the order in e.g. the heading. How can I reorder it there as well?